# passing javascript variable in iframe

Tags: javascript

i am trying to pass javascript variable in iframe

here is index.html in first domain

```
 <script>var details ='test999'</script>;
 <iframe src="http://somedomain.com/99.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" ;scrolling="yes""></iframe>
```

and in other domain i am uploading 99.html with below code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#prithere").html('' + details + '');
  });
</script>

<div id="prithere"></div>
```

i am not getting cross origin issue i am getting this undefined error.  Uncaught ReferenceError: details is not defined
 is this because code is executed before iframe is loaded? if so any solution ?
i cant use onclick

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you could, it would be `parent.details` but just pass it to the page:

```
<script>
var details ='test999'; 
document.write('<iframe src="http://somedomain.com/99.html#details='+details+'"....</iframe>');
</script>
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#prithere").html(location.hash.split("details=")[1]);
});
```

Comment: Using hash "#" would be better: `'http://somedomain.com/99.html#'+details`. This way you would let the browser cache work as usual.